# Mapping hibernate boolean to smallint PostgreSql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

```
 @NativeQuery
    List<OperationUnit> findOperationUnitByOuTypeIDSql(@QueryParam("ouTypeId") Long ouTypeId, @QueryParam("isAvailable") Boolean isAvailable, RowMapper<OperationUnit> rowMapper);
```

my query:

```
select * from t_au_operation_unit  where OU_TYPE_ID = :ouTypeId and is_available = :isAvailable order by name asc;
```

I've got this function in Java .As you can see, `isAvailable` is Boolean type. However, the related column in Postgres db is `smallint` type. Therefore, I've got this kind of error

> ERROR: operator does not exist: smallint = boolean

Comment: Why are you storing a `boolean` as a `smallint` and not as a `boolean`?

Comment: cos i did the db conversion from oracle to pgsql. In oracle, the column is_avaiable is NUMBER(1) and the related type in Pgsql is smallint

Answer (score 0):

Why not using named query 
select op from OperationUnit op where op.ouTypeId = :ouTypeId and op.isAvailable = :isAvailable

If you insits to use native query you should convert the parameter isAvailible from boolean to an integer (maybe in client side before sending it to the controller)
HTH

Comment: how to convert the paramter is_available  from boolean to an integer in client side?

Comment: If you are sending Ajax request easily make URL=URL+isAvailible =?1:0 if working with spring model change the model to have an int value calculted by isAvailibe int getOtherAvilible(){ return isAvilible ? 1 :0} and use this parameter